# Internal CA for Digital Signature Solution - PKI Based

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

I'm trying to set up a digital signature solution which would work with a internal PKI.

We have considered Microsoft Certificate Services, but we don't want to rule out any other option to set up a CA.

Do you know what other open-source options do we have?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's *Certificate Services* **is** a CA. It does its job reasonably well(*) as long as you comply to "the Microsoft way", which means Active Directory throughout, with domains and forests and federation. This usually implies several dedicated servers.

As for open-source solutions, I heard good things about [EJBCA](http://ejbca.sourceforge.net/). Some people try to do PKI "by hand" with [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) (the command-line tool), but this means that you will basically write your own PKI (95% of PKI is *procedures*, not software) and this requires a thorough understanding of the arcanes of [X.509](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280). This is not a good plan for the unwary.

<sup>(*) Except that it does not scale well at all; the CA becomes sluggish after 50k issued certificates, unusable at 300k.</sup>